# Mongoose - TypeError: Object is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Since other solutions didn't work for me:

**mongoose/connection.js** *(Console is printing - - Mongo DB connected .)*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = process.env.URL,
options = {
  user: process.env.DBUSER,
  pass: process.env.DBPASSWORD
};

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(url, options);

connection.on('error', function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
});

connection.once('open', function callback () {
  console.info('- - Mongo DB connected .');
});

module.exports = connection;
```

**mongoose/model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Event = new Schema({
   event_code: String
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Event', Event);
module.export = Model;
```

**mongoose/database.js**

```
function newLiveEvent (event_code, callback) {

  var LiveEvent = require ('./model.js');

  var newEvent = new LiveEvent({
     event_code: event_code
  });

  newEvent.save(function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Event saved !')
  });

  callback();

}
```

**ISSUE** A simple form sends a post request with event_code, couldn't be simplier.

This is what I get when the newLiveEvent function gets fired ...
`TypeError: LiveEvent is not a constructor`

There were several other questions asked about this, sadly their solution did not work for me, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database file you should require the model, the connection and finally create the LiveEvent as connection.model('Event') to be able to call save method.

Comment: Ok within my database.js file I called my model and connection ... and the LiveEvent as `connection.model('Event')` ... and now it works ! THANK YOU SO MUCH !